# Haskell induction - I fail to see why this solution proves anything

Tags: haskell, induction

The following is from a homework that I already did, and did wrong. I fail to see why the solution is sufficient. (After one week of reading and googling I turn to asking.)

The example is similar to an example used in the Hutton book on Haskell.

```
Base case:

add Zero m
=   { applying add }
m
=   { property of add }
add m Zero

Inductive case:

add (Succ n) m
=   { applying add }
Succ (add n m)
=   { induction hypothesis }
Succ (add m n)
=   { property of add }
add m (Succ n)



-- Hypothesis:
add n m = add m n

-- Method:
by induction on n

-- Using:
add n (Succ m) = Succ (add n m)
add n Zero = n

data Nat = Zero
         | Succ Nat


add :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
add Zero m = m
add (Succ n) m = Succ (add n m)
```

What I fail to see is why the induction case is allowed to stop where it stops. It uses the hypothesis, and then un-applies add to generate something that is the version of the hypothesis of the induction case.

```
add n m = add m n -- hypothesis
add m (Succ n)  -- hypthesis applied to the induction case add (Succ n) m
```

In other words, another version of the hypothesis was generated by already assuming that the hypothesis holds.

That is enough? Can I always treat the hypothesis as valid when I find one single case in which it works? And for the inductive case it is always sufficient if I can generate a version of the hypothesis applied to the inductive case by assuming that the hypothesis itself is already proven?

I have troubles to transfer induction from numbers to function. Please don't let me die stupid. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> That is enough? Can I always treat the hypothesis as valid when I find one single case in which it works?

No. You need to:

1. Show it works for all base (non-recursive) cases. Here you have only one: `Zero`. So you need to show

> `add Zero m = add m Zero` holds.

2. Show that for all recursive cases, assuming the hypothesis for arguments is sufficient to show it for the constructed result. Again, here the only recursive case is `Succ`; so you need to show that

> *given* `add n m = add m n`, `add (Succ n) m = add m (Succ n)` holds.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it helps if you spell out the problem more formally, including forall quantifiers:

```
forall (n m : Nat), add n m = add m n
```

## Induction over n

Apply the induction principle:

```
forall m, add 0 m = add m 0 
          -> (forall n m, add n m = add m n -> add (S n) m = add m (S n)) 
          -> forall n m, add n m = add m n
```

Now we need to prove the base case `add Z m = add m Z` and the inductive case `forall n m, add n m = add m n -> add (S n) m = add m (S n)`

#### Base case: `forall m, add Z m = add m Z`

Let `m` be any `Nat` (this is called introduction).

- Apply `add` to LHS and you get `m = add m Z`.
- Apply `forall m, add m Z = m` (You can prove this if you want) to rewrite RHS and you get `m = m`.

This holds by reflexivity of equality.

#### Inductive case `forall n m, add n m = add m n -> add (S n) m = add m (S n)`

Let `n`, `m` be any `Nat` and introduce the hypothesis `add n m = add m n` (i.e. assume that it holds)

Goal: `add (S n) m = add m (S n)`

- Apply `add` to LHS: `S (add n m) = add m (S n)`
- Rewrite using hypothesis: `S (add m n) = add m (S n)`
- Apply `forall x y, S (add x y) = add (S x) y` (again, you can prove this if you want to) to LHS to get `add m (S n) = add m (S n)`.

This holds by reflexivity.

And we're done.

Answer (score -1):

Try an example.

```
3 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 0
```

so in `Nat`, `3` is represented as `Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))`. Now for any `m :: Nat`, (consider the two cases: `Zero` and `Succ (Succ (... (Succ Zero) ...)`)

we have

```
add (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))) m = 
Succ (add (Succ (Succ Zero)) m) = -- we took 1 from 3 and added it to the overall answer
Succ (Succ (add (Succ Zero) m)) = -- ditto
Succ (Succ (Succ (add Zero m))) = -- ditto
Succ (Succ (Succ m)) -- by applying the base case for `add`
```

So we see the result is "whatever `m` was (0 or otherwise), plus three more", or `m+3` as you would expect.